# Parse all rows and columns on a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

there! I have a df with 502489 rows × 103 columns.

Each row corresponds to a participant and each column to values taken at different time.
I want to create a function that looks through the rows and columns and selects the participants (rows) who had a particular value (==1135) anytime (in any columns). I tried with loc and set, but it did not work, as it required to specify the columns name, but it is unfeasible in this way as I have 103 columns and I want to look for any of them. Any suggestions, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSE75.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over [`df.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) to get the participants of the dataframe, and use that to construct a bool list with a value for every participant. Then you can use `df.loc` to get the rows for which there is a `True` value in the bool list:

```py
bool_list = []
for participant in df.itertuples(name=None):
    bool_list.append(1135 in participant)
print(df.loc(bool_list))
```

Using comprehensions that can be reduced to a single line of code:

```py
print(df.loc[(1135 in participant for participant in df.itertuples(name=None))])
```

---

Another way to do it without `df.itertuples` (which I think is considered *bad practice*), is to use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` to get the bool list:

```py
print(df.loc[df.apply(lambda row: 1135 in row, axis=1, raw=True)]
```

---

**Time Comparisons:**

```py
>>> timeit('df.loc[(1135 in row for row in df.itertuples(name=None))]', globals={'df': df}, number=5000)
3.968556400000125
>>> timeit('df.loc[df.apply(lambda row: 1135 in row, axis=1, raw=True)]', globals={'df': df}, number=5000)
4.834247799999957
```

Opposed to everything I've been reading (which, admittingly, is not a lot) the first method is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is not perfect but working solution:

```
list = [['col0','col1','col2','col3','col4'],
    ['valjk','valj','valjo','valhl','valjk'],
    ['valnjk','bkl','ijl','bkbk','vall;'],
    ['mkl','search1','ml;','mkl','bhj'],
    ['bjk','bkj','hvbj','lkl','hkl'],
    ['vhj','vhj','nl','gh','cty'],
    ['vjbh','uik','bjj','vuhjb','bnl'],
    ['vbhj','bknk','jk','seach2','vbhkjn'],
    ['vbhj','bjn','ml;','njm ','rf'],
    ['vbhj','bjn','ml;','njm ','rf'],
    ['vbjkhj','bknk','jk','hjhk','search1'],
    ['vbhj','bjn','search1','njm ','rf'],
    ['vbhj','bjn','ml;','njm ','rf'],
    ['fty','search1','rtyj','dfgh','yy']
    ]

 df = pd.DataFrame(list[1:],columns=list[0])
 selected= []
 frames = []
for d in df.columns:
   selected.append(df.loc[df[d] == 'search1'])
for k in range(len(selected)):
   if(not selected[k].empty):
      frames.append(selected[k])
result = pd.concat(frames)  
print(result)
```

The result is:

```
   col0     col1     col2  col3     col4
   mkl  search1      ml;   mkl      bhj
  fty  search1     rtyj  dfgh       yy
 vbhj      bjn  search1  njm        rf
vbjkhj     bknk       jk  hjhk  search1
```